# Multilang Wordpress site with domains and subdomains

Tags: wordpress

I'm looking for a WP plugin that will let me create a multilang site where each subdomain or domain will represent separate translation. E.g. example.com for english, de.example.com for german, examplejp.com for japanese.

I found polylang and bogo plugins, but not sure if they support domains and subdomains the way I need.

Does anyone have an experience in this?

Thanks!

Comment: zTranslate is a good one.

Answer (score 0):

Make a multisite with WordPress, then add subsites (de, jp, etc.), upload languages files into /wp-content/languages directory, plus set the subsites main language to the required (de, jp, etc.) on General Settings page (/wp-admin/options-general.php).